# Costs of SolidBrush Object?

Tags: direct2d

Is it (memory/performance-wise) better to a) create SolidBrushes for all colors needed or b) create one SolidBrush and change the color with the SetColor method:

```
        m_pSolidColorBrush->SetColor(
        D2D1::ColorF(
            0.0f,
            intensity,
            1.0f - intensity
            ));
```

?

I haven't found any documentation or useful code samples..

Answer (score 0):

Performance test result: SetColor() is much faster and works fine.